# Is it possible to use motherboard video ports for additional monitors when a CPU does not have integrated graphics?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, motherboard, integrated-graphics

I am adding more monitors to my display configuration, and have depleted all my ports on my graphics card. I have tried to use a HDMI port on my motherboard, however my PC does not detect the new display or send a video output to it through the motherboard video port. My CPU does not have integrated graphics, and I could not find a setting in my BIOS to force a video output

**Is it possible to use motherboard video ports with CPU without integrated graphics?** If not, why?

I have ruled out problems with the monitor and cables by successfully testing the monitor with the video ports on my graphics card.

My current relevant specs, although this section is intentionally ambiguous to help others with a similar question and different hardware.

- Motherboard: [B450 Tomahawk](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/B450-TOMAHAWK/Specification)
- CPU: [Ryzen 5 3600](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-5-3600) @ stock
- GPU: Nvidia GTX 1050 Ti

  ---

A [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/760493/is-it-possible-to-use-a-nvidia-gpu-to-render-graphics-if-the-monitor-is-connecte) asked about forwarding GPU rendered graphics, but did not feature a situation that lacked integrated graphics.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable Onboard Graphics for a GIGABYTE B450 PRO](https://superuser.com/questions/1503683/how-to-enable-onboard-graphics-for-a-gigabyte-b450-pro).  While the author of the duplicate asked about a different CPU and motherboard, the answer to your question, exactly the same.  **Your hardware for not support what you want to do.**

Answer (score 2):

OK, first you cannot. It's impossible. Because motherboards are made that way. I just say, do an SLI or Crossfire (because these two does two Graphics Cards) and also you can use ports from your nVIDIA 1050 Ti (I don't have them).

But if it's not enough, just like, do some shopping on some video splitters (well, with the port of your choice) and connect it. But I don't know if you like it. This displays both the image. Here's some examples:

- [HDMI port splitter from Walmart](https://www.walmart.com/ip/3-Port-HDMI-Splitter-Switch-Cable-2ft-3-In-1-out-Auto-High-Speed-Switcher-Splitter-Support-3D-1080P-For-HDTV-DVD/452191269) (lol)
- [VGA port spitter from Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005H3I38G) (wow)
- [DisplayPort splitter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005H3I38G)
- DVI port splitter can't find it

Comment: My first answer is voted the best answer to this question!

Answer (score 0):

No.

If you don't have a GPU (Graphical Processing Unit) to make a signal for a port, that port won't do anything. You'll need to add another video adapter, either internal or external, and the externals are incredibly slow if you don't have a Thunderbolt 3 port on your motherboard (I checked, you don't).